# Newline in Objective C using Xcode 4.4

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, escaping, nslog

Has anyone had an issue besides me where /n didn't produce a new line in an output string?  This is a starter program taken from "Programming in Objective C" Fourth Edition by Stephen Kochan.  The code runs without error but prints /n instead of advancing a line which is contrary to the text.  Is there an Xcode dialog setting I need to look at or something?

Thanks,

Michael

```
//  First programming example

#import <'Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Testing..../n....1/n....2/n....3");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The " and ' in the import statement are not in the actual code.  I needed to stick those in order for the Stack Overflow editor to keep from truncating or formatting the line.

Comment: To format your code properly, either indent each line with 4 spaces, or select all your code and hit the `{ }` icon to get pretty formatting. :)

Answer (score 8):

Newline character in Objective-C (and also many other programming languages...) is `\n` not `/n`.

Comment: you beat to it because my first attempts to answer were too short >=[ --- hahaha :) +1

Answer (score 4):

Escaping characters is when you use a backslash, not a forward slash, a new line is: `\n` and a carriage return is `\r`

`/n` is just... well "/n"

Comment: Heh, I'm pretty sure you meant 'carriage return' rather than 'cartridge return.' Let me guess...typing in a hurry + autocorrect?  :-)

Comment: Stackoverflow and iPad isn't such a good combination... Good spot. Corrected.

Comment: actually cartridge return is also ok - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return :)